# Angular4 : How to retrieve data from model class

Tags: angular

I am working in an Angular4 application ,In this I am storing API response to model class ,Now I want to retrieve data from model class in specific component,I have tried something but I can't get the values.

Model class

```
export interface Images {
  big_Images: BImage[];
  small_Images: Simage[];
  selected_Product_Images: SelectedImage[]
}

export interface BImage {
  big_Images: string;
}

export interface Simage {
  small_Images: string;
}

export interface SelectedImage {
  selected_Product_Image: string;
}
```

component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CartdataService } from './cartdata.service';
import { Images } from './model';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  constructor(private CartdataService: CartdataService) {}

   images : Images;

   ngOnInit() {
    this.CartdataService.i_cast_Product_Path.subscribe( (response : Images ) =>
    { this.images = response; });
  }
}
```

API res

[image]

I want to print each data in a span tag

[image]

Comment: Your JSON doesn't match your Interface. I am assuming that `i_cast_Product_Path` returns `Images`. But you cannot deseralize the json you have shown into the `Images` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I assumed your response JSON matches the interface.

**Option 01**

**cartdata.service.ts**

Import below modules

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {Http,Request,Response,Headers, RequestOptions} from "@angular/http";

get_Product_Path(pName: string) : Observable<any> {
     let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
     let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    this.current_product = pName.trim();
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:abc/api/data/GetImage/?imageName=${this.current_product}`,options);

  }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.CartdataService.get_Product_Path('').subscribe(response =>
    { 
        console.log(response);
        this.images = response.json(); 
    });
  }
```

I hope this will help you. If you have any problem or doubt let me know.

Comment: It returns response.json is not a function

Comment: @Siva can you console.log(response); and post it with your question?

Comment: Natha Please check the console output in the above image

Comment: @SivaM No brother, What I asked was put a console.log like this and attach the screenshot

this.CartdataService.i_cast_Product_Path.subscribe( (response : Images ) =>
    { 
        console.log(response); 
        this.images = response; 
});

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkmfsu?file=app%2Fcartdata.service.ts   Please take a look at this

Comment: Any particular reason for using BehaviorSubject?? @SivaM

Comment: No,I can go with other techniques

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168098/discussion-between-suvethan-nantha-and-siva-m).